# Parsing a long query string directly to MongoDB (just like you can in SQL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In PHP or C++ or Java etc. I can send a whole long complex query to MySql

```
myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE STATUS < 5 ORDER BY CHECKIN';
resultArray = mySql_query(myConnnect,myQuery);
```

Now I am working with MEAN using MongoDB.
Is there a way to do the same here?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get(myDatabase, function(req, res){

    my-long-query = 'db.getCollection("receipt").aggregate([{$match:{bookingId:"94JCI"}},{$project:{"_id":0,"receiptNo":1,"amount":1}}])'
    db.myDatabase.parse-my-long-query(function(err, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });

});
```

Some of the queries are really long and I generate them dynamically
Right now I copy paste them to Robomongo test the results.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you generating them? From a DB call or from a URL? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger I just generate them in javascript based on the content of a lot of fields and logic, and at the moment I parse the long query to console, copy and past to Robomongo and run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run queries directly using `db.command`in node js.

Aggregation query as db command takes the below form.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#aggregate-data-with-multi-stage-pipeline

Adjust your javascript to send information as key value pairs. Key each for `collectionname` and `query` and pass their values into the below command.

`db.command( aggregate: collectionname,
   pipeline: query,
   cursor: { }
}`

Different types of queries has different syntax. So you've to pass key value pair accordingly in `db.command`.

More here

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/

Comment: Thanks once again Veeram :-)   This was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: so if I have to parse something like this, how would it look?
db.getCollection("contactlist").aggregate([{$match:{name:"Tim"}},{$project:{"_id":0,"name":1,"number":1}}])

Comment: Probably like this: `

var myFunction = function(req, res) {
    db.contactlist.aggregate( [
        { $match: { name: "Tim" } },
        { $project : {"_id":0,"name":1,"number":1} },      
    ], function(err, doc) {
        console.log('XXX ' + doc);
        res.json(doc);
    });
};`

Comment: You are welcome. Try something like `var myFunction = function(req, res) { db.command(  {
   aggregate:req.body.collectionname,
   pipeline: req.body.query,
   cursor: { }
}, function(err, doc) { console.log('XXX ' + doc); res.json(doc); }); };`. Your request should be `{"collectionname":"contactlist", "query":[ { $match: { name: "Tim" } }, { $project : {"_id":0,"name":1,"number":1} }]}`