# NodeJS storing mongo aggregate query in DB or property file

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have below mongo aggregate query in my nodejs api. It's working absolute fine.

```
queryRes = await Seller.aggregate([
  {$match: {}},{$addFields : {"communication_information":{$filter:{ input: "$communication_information",as: "communication_information",
       cond: {"$or" :[{$eq: ["$$communication_information.communication_information_type",  "phone"  ] },
                {$eq: ["$$communication_information.communication_information_type", "email"] },
                ]}}}}},{ "$project": {"_id": 1,"initial_name": 1,"first_name": 1,"last_name": 1,"gender":1,"communication_information":1, }},
                { $sort : { first_name : 1, last_name: 1 } },])
```

What I am trying to achieve is, **want to store this query in either some property file or in database itself and fetch query string base on some logic and execute it.**
In Java I'm able to do this. I can store all my application queries in property file to void compiling whole application once queries needs updates.

Can similar be achieve in NodeJs. I am using Mongoose for connecting MongoDB?
What I am able to achieve so far is, I am able to store above query in MongoDB and get the string in variable.

```
queryGetter = await Queries.find()
const queryString = queryGetter.qstring             // storing query string
queryRes = await Seller.aggregate(queryString)
```

but this give error

```
"Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators"
```

Thank in advance for any clues to achieve this

Comment: If you are storing json string in db and retrieving then you need to parse the string `JSON.parse(queryString)`.

Comment: JSON.parse(queryString) gives more error it's not accepting $match:{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have inserted properly stringify query, like below:

```
let string_query = JSON.stringify(Your Query Object);
```

then you can get parse, like below:

```
let object_query = JSON.parse(string_query);
```

Working exampple with your query:

```js
// YOUR ORIGINAL QUERY
let original_query = [
        {$match: {}},{$addFields : {"communication_information":{$filter:{ input: "$communication_information",as: "communication_information",
             cond: {"$or" :[{$eq: ["$$communication_information.communication_information_type",  "phone"  ] },
                      {$eq: ["$$communication_information.communication_information_type", "email"] },
                      ]}}}}},{ "$project": {"_id": 1,"initial_name": 1,"first_name": 1,"last_name": 1,"gender":1,"communication_information":1, }},
                      { $sort : { first_name : 1, last_name: 1 } },];

// STRINGIFY QUERY FOR STORING IN DB PURPOSE
let string_query = JSON.stringify(original_query);

console.log("Stringiy Query: ", string_query);

// PARSE AGAIN WHEN YOU FETCH FROM DB
let parsed_query = JSON.parse(string_query);

console.log("Parsed Query: ", parsed_query);
```

---

If you have already stored your query in DB and there is some issues in stringify, because of long query it will cause an error, you can try [db.command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572827/8987128)

Comment: thanks it worked. somehow its not working when I am retrieving it from mongodb but put this in .JSON file, it worked.